# why isn't my background color changing for my view in swift?

Tags: swift, uiview, uicolor

I am trying to change my background color for my view programmatically because later on I will have to switch the color based on user input. I have no idea why this wont change the background color.

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet weak var rLabel: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var gLabel: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var bLabel: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet weak var largeColorView: UIView!



 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    func colorWithAlphaComponent(alpha: CGFloat) -> UIColor{
      let newColor = UIColor.init(red: 0.5, green: 0.8, blue: 1.0, alpha: alpha)
      return newColor
    }
    print(largeColorView.backgroundColor)
    print(colorWithAlphaComponent(1.0))
    largeColorView.backgroundColor! = colorWithAlphaComponent(1.0)
    print(largeColorView.backgroundColor)

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
  }
```

Comment: this code will work, but where is your code which changed colors?

Comment: i haven't created it yet. This code wasn't changing my background color

Comment: try run on a simulator

Answer (score 1):

First mistake : you have to implement the function outside of the the viewDidLoad() method but you call of it.
Therefore your code should like this :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print(largeColorView.backgroundColor)
    print(colorWithAlphaComponent(1.0))
    largeColorView.backgroundColor! = colorWithAlphaComponent(1.0)
    print(largeColorView.backgroundColor)
  }

func colorWithAlphaComponent(alpha: CGFloat) -> UIColor{
  let newColor = UIColor.init(red: 0.5, green: 0.8, blue: 1.0, alpha: alpha)
  return newColor
}
```

**Therefore this line of code will run because it call the function**

```
largeColorView.backgroundColor! = colorWithAlphaComponent(1.0)
```